# Capturing a byte[] image data from WPFMediaKit

Tags: c#, bitmapdata

I have a bit of code that I have been working with to capture an image from a VideoCaptureElement from WPFMediaKit. It works great!

```
    bmp.Render(videoElement);
    BitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
    string now = DateTime.Now.Year + "" + DateTime.Now.Month + "" + DateTime.Now.Day + "" + DateTime.Now.Hour + "" + DateTime.Now.Minute + "" + DateTime.Now.Second;
    string filename = now + "pic.jpg";
    FileStream fstream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
    encoder.Save(fstream);
    fstream.Close();
```

The problem I am facing though is that I need to get a byte[] data now rather than save a file. Currently I am doing this with a open filedialog box and a filestream:

```
            if (File.Exists(FileLocation))
            {
                // Retrieve image from file and binary it to Object image
                using (FileStream stream = File.Open(FileLocation, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream);
                    byte[] data = br.ReadBytes(maxImageSize);
                    image = new Image(dlg.SafeFileName, data, fileSize);
                }
            }
```

What I'd like to do is to take the capture and rather than save a file, I'd like to get it as a `byte[]` type. Is there a way to convert either `RenderTargetBitmap` or `BitmapEncoder` to a `byte[]` array?

Or possibly I'm thinking to convert those to a memory stream so a binary reader can use it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want raw data, or a bmp file in memory (with header)?

Answer (score 1):

To convert an BitmapSource to a byte array you can do something like this,
Where bmp is your BitmapSource or RenderTargetBitmap.

```
BitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));

byte[] arr = null;
using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    encoder.Save(memStream);
    arr = stream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: +1, `memStream.ToArray()` is a slightly easier way to convert the memory stream to a byte array.

Comment: is memstream.length the filesize?

Comment: thanks for that vcsjones and memstream.length is the length in bytes of the stream, so yes, you could say its the file size of the image you added to the encoder.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the already mentioned saving to a stream in bmp format, you can also call `CopyPixels` on a BitmapSource.

That will give you the original pixels, in the original format, with no header.

See [this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.copypixels.aspx)